# Syntax in IIS to use re-write subdomain as path of {HTTP_HOST}

Tags: redirect, iis, syntax, url-rewriting

Suppose I have a site: `https://sub.domain.example`, what is the proper syntax to get this to become `https://domain.example/sub`

The need is regardless of the sub and the Toplevel domain (e.g., .com,.net,.org) to have the redirect push the user to `https://domain.example/sub`
Here is what I have tried but no go--

```
<rules>
  <rule name="SubDomain to Subdirectory">
   <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(\w+)\.(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://domain.example/{C:1}" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: HTTP_HOST is not the domain, it includes the `http://` and port. So try to use SERVER_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below rule to achieve your requiremnet:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([_0-9a-z-]+)\.(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.example/{C:1}" />
            </rule>
```